# How to change the query based on the user dropdown selection option?

Tags: php, ajax

I have created a plugin for my WordPress website. This plugin has its won table on db and one of it's column is month. I use an widget to display data based on the actual month query. Every thing is fine except I can't worked out how to display monthly data when visitor select a different month, rather than actual month. After the new data loaded it has to remain on the same page with out refreshing the page.

```
<div class="st-container-bottom">
    <div class="st-download"><a href="#" title="full timetable" class="full-timetable">&gt; Download Full Prayer Timetable</a></div>
    <span class="st-close"><a title="Close"></a></span>
    <div class="st-change">
        <select id="st-tt">
            <option value="01">January</option>
            <option value="02">February</option>
            <option value="03">March</option>
            <option value="04">April</option>
            <option value="05">May</option>
            <option value="06">June</option>
            <option value="07">July</option>
            <option value="08">August</option>
            <option value="09">September</option>
            <option value="10">October</option>
            <option value="11">November</option>
            <option value="12" selected="">December</option>
        </select>
        <span class="ld-img" style="display: none;">loading...</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try ajax to get required data without refresh the page.

Example :

```
 $.ajax({
  url: 'example.php',
  type: 'post',
  data: {'st-tt': $('#st-tt').val()},
  success: function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  }
});
```

This is just example. try it.

Comment: I have tried that but I did not get the result. Below are the widget codes. Please can you show me how to do that?

Comment: in example.php write code to you want get same page

Comment: I can't figured out. Please what i need is to change the db query based on selection: $entry_prayer = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix . "mwh_salat." "WHERE month=01"); So month should be based on visitor selection